# having trouble running a batch file from my C# windows application

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a batch file that runs another batch file from my windows application.

when i click the button, everything is frozen and i do not know why.
The nested batch file was created to build html files from RST files
I have a feeling that I am in a dead lock situation.
Thank you so much guys for your help.
I have attached a screen shot of my form and included my code as well.

```
private void buttonMakeHtml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = 
            new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c" + "\"C:\\ReadTheDocs\\makeHtml.bat\"");

    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


    processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

    process.WaitForExit();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    textBoxOutPut.Text = output;
    textBoxError.Text = error;

}
```

[Make html Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/483Ht.png)

Comment: If it freezes, then your script is probably waiting for an input before finishing.

Comment: I do not think so. the batch file actually runs another batch which creates the html files. here is the code for the batch file.. it simple.

@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
c:
cd readthedocs/
make html
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT

Comment: `pause` makes the script wait for an input before finishing. Note how this phrase is almost identical to the one I wrote above, without having seen your code.

Comment: Could you post the script?

Comment: I just want to add the code of the batch file. it is very simple.

@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
c:
cd readthedocs/
make html
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT

Comment: `
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
c:
cd readthedocs/
make html
ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
`